# Generic makefile target for object files in multiple subdirectories

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, gnu-make

I have a project with the following directory structure:

```
Root directory
    bin/ (for final executable)
    Mod1/
        build/ (for *.o / *.d files)
        inc/
        src/
    Mod2/
        build/
        inc/
        src/
    Mod.../ (future module directories)
        build/
        inc/
        src/
    makefile
```

My current makefile contains this:

```
# Directory naming conventions
SRC_DIR_NAME = src
BUILD_DIR_NAME = build

# Parallel source/object/dependency file lists
SRCS = $(shell find -name *.cpp)
OBJS = $(subst $(SRC_DIR_NAME),$(BUILD_DIR_NAME),$(SRCS:%.cpp=%.o))

# Final executable
APP = bin/app

build: $(APP)

$(APP): $(OBJS)
    # link objects and compile app

%.o: %.cpp
    # compile sources into objects
```

My file lists work as expected and produce:

```
SRCS=./mod1/src/file.cpp ./mod2/src/file.cpp
OBJS=./mod1/build/file.o ./mod2/build/file.o
DEPS=./mod1/build/file.d ./mod2/build/file.d
```

However when I run make I get the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `mod1/build/file.o', needed by `/bin/app'.  Stop.
```

My assumption is that:

`%.o: %.cpp`

Doesn't work with a input like

`mod1/build/file.o`

Is there a way to make a generic target that takes a module directory and creates targets for that module's object files that require that module's source files in their respective sub-directories?

I know using recursive make can solve this issue but I want to avoid having to use that solution if possible.

Comment: This is what [static pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) are for. Well one thing they are useful for at least.

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm still not making any progress. Is there anyway to pass multiple % wildcards to a target? (e.g. %/build/%.o: %/src/%.cpp)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to express such sophisticated target in GNU Make. Although there is a way to generate the set of targets (and corresponding rules). Except an obvious way to use some tool to generate Makefile, we can use [eval](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html) feature of GNU Make to create rules programmatically. Example code is following.

```
# Directory naming conventions
SRC_DIR_NAME := src
BUILD_DIR_NAME := build

# source files list
SRCS := $(shell find -name '*.cpp')

# function to get obj file name from src file name
OBJ_FROM_SRC = $(subst /$(SRC_DIR_NAME)/,/$(BUILD_DIR_NAME)/,$(1:%.cpp=%.o))

# Final executable
APP := bin/app

.PHONY: build
.DEFAULT_GOAL := build

# rule template for obj
define obj_rule_by_src =
src := $(1)
obj := $$(call OBJ_FROM_SRC,$$(src))
OBJS := $$(OBJS) $$(obj)
$$(obj): $$(src)
    # compile source into object
    echo build $$@ from $$<
endef

# generate rules for OBJS
$(foreach src,$(SRCS),$(eval $(call obj_rule_by_src,$(src))))


$(APP): $(OBJS)
# link objects and compile app
    echo create $@ from $^

build: $(APP)
```